# Prove that $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{z}{1-z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for $|z|<1$, one have
$$
\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\cdots+\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}+\cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}
$$
and
$$
\frac{z}{1+z}+\frac{2z^2}{1+z^2}+\cdots+\frac{2^k z^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}+\cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}
$$
Use the dyadic expansion of an integer and the fact that $2^{k+1}-1=1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^k$.

Comment: Since you had the hint at hand already, did you try using it?

Comment: Hint (for the first part:) Every positive integer can be written in exactly one way as $2^n+2^{n+1}k$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dyadic expansion, so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Dyadic just means "binary" or "base 2."

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{z^{2^k}}{1-z^{2^{k+1}}}&=z^{2^k}\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(z^{2^{k+1}}\right)^n\\
&=z^{2^k}\sum_{n\ge 0}z^{2^{k+1}n}\\
&=\sum\left\{z^n:1\le n\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}\right\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{z^{2^k}}{1-z^{2^{k+1}}}&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum\left\{z^n:1\le n\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}\right\}\\
&=\sum\bigcup_{k\ge 0}\left\{z^n:1\le n\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}\right\}\\
&=\sum\left\{z^n:\exists k\ge 0\left(n\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}\right)\right\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Moreover,

$$\frac{z}{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge 1}z^n\;.$$

Now show that for each positive integer $n$ there is a unique non-negative integer $k$ such that $n\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}$. The dyadic expansion of $n$ may help you here.

For the second question, note that

$$\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}=2^kz^{2^k}\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nz^{2^kn}=2^k\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nz^{2^k(n+1)}\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}=\sum_{k\ge 0}2^k\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nz^{2^{k(n+1)}}\;.\tag{1}$$

Show that if if $n=2^km$, where $k\ge 0$ and $m$ is odd, then the coefficient of $z^n$ in $(1)$ is $$\sum_{\ell=0}^k(-1)^{2^{k-\ell}m-1}2^\ell\;,$$ and evaluate this finite sum to find the coefficient of $z^n$ in $(1)$.

Comment: How do you show that the LHS of each equation converges absolutely? Don't we need that to justify switching the summation.

Comment: @Andrew: You can use the ratio test on both of the original lefthand sides.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you help me with the last statement? I can't find out how to find the coefficient of $z^n$ in (1).